# Sort data of another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to sort data of sheet3 from rangeB10 (headers on Row no.10) till last used column and row and sort based on Column C11:C

I am not sure how do I code this.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim lcol, lrow As Long
    
    
    lcol = Cells(10, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lrow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=Range("A1"), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
      
       Sheet3.Sort.SortFields.Clear
       Sheet3.Sort.SortFields.Add Key _
            :=Range("C11:C"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending,
            DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        
        With Sheet3.Sort
            .SetRange Range(Cells(10, 2), Cells(lrow, lcol))
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Could you make it more clear as I am a beginner?

Comment: My active sheet will be sheet7 and want my code to go sheet3 and sort data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of Cells, Range, Columns are implicit references to ActiveSheet. Add `Sheet3.` to all these,

Excel does not support a range reference like "C11:C". Change that to `"C11:C" & Sheet3.Rows.Count`.

Your code Dims `lcol` as Variant. Change that to `As Long`

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    Dim lcol As Long, lrow As Long
    
    lcol = Sheet3.Cells(10, Sheet3.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lrow = Sheet3.Cells.Find( _
      What:="*", _
      After:=Sheet3.Range("A1"), _
      LookAt:=xlPart, _
      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
      MatchCase:=False).Row
      
    Sheet3.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Sheet3.Sort.SortFields.Add _
      Key:=Sheet3.Range("C11:C" & Sheet3.Rows.Count), _
      SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
      Order:=xlAscending, _ 
      DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        
    With Sheet3.Sort
        .SetRange Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Cells(10, 2), Sheet3.Cells(lrow, lcol))
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```